# How to convert linq query to non-query expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I use EF6, I have this linq to entity query:

```
   from s in SensorObservationEntities.SensorsMeasures
            group s by s.SensorUnitId into g
            let latest = g.OrderByDescending(s => s.MeasureDate).FirstOrDefault()
            select latest
```

How can I convet it to non-query expression?

Comment: With your amount of reputation you should know that you need to tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert this to the method syntax version, you can do this step by step. I like to start at the end and work through to the beginning:

1. `select` to `Select` defines the source:

   ```
   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.MeasureDate).FirstOrDefault());
   ```
2. `group` is `GroupBy`:

   ```
   .GroupBy(s => s.SensorUnitId)
   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.MeasureDate).FirstOrDefault());
   ```
3. `from` the source

   ```
   SensorObservationEntities.SensorsMeasures
   .GroupBy(s => s.SensorUnitId)
   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.MeasureDate).FirstOrDefault());
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You mean method syntax :

```
SensorObservationEntities.SensorsMeasures.GroupBy(g => g.SensorUnitId)
             .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasureDate).FirstOrDefault());
```